# No mail file for users in /var/mail

Tags: 14.04, postfix, dovecot

Using ubuntu server 14.03. When I open mutt it complains that /var/mail/michael (the user created during the install) does not exists. I then decided to create another user using webmin and again mutt complains with the same message about that user. Is there a config file I should be messing with to have the mail files created? 
Thanks in advance for ANY input.

Comment: Did you send any mail to the user? The mail file won't exist unless the user has received some mail.

Answer (score 1):

mutt open $MAIL.
if $MAIL does not exist then mutt "complains".
what else can i do but tell you about it?

you can create $MAIL by touching it:

```
    $ touch $MAIL
```

now mutt should open that.

nothing to read?  send yourself an email!

```
    $ date | mutt -s test $USER
```

instant email - yay! :)